# Not routes match with URL generation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Rails.So forgive me if the question seems dumb.I am creating an application in which users can upload stories for others to read.On sign in, they can create their profile as well.Now once the user submits a story,in the story index page, I try to list the story title along with the name of the submitter.I am trying to make the name of the submitter as a link which will display the profile show page of the submitter.This however does not seems to work.I tried various stuff, but it does not gives me the solution.
Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
:authentication_keys => [:login]
has_many :stories
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
attr_accessor :login
validate :validate_username
```

here is my profile model

```
belongs_to :user
```

This is my profile controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
#before_action :find_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
end

def new
    @profile = Profile.new
end

def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  @profile.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @profile.save
  flash[:success] = "Profile saved"
  redirect_to root_path
  else
  flash[:error] = "Error"
  render :new
  end
end

def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
  flash[:success] = "Successfully updated"    # Optional
  redirect_to profile_path
  else
  flash[:error] = "Error"       # Optional
  render :edit
end
end

def edit
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
end

private

 def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit
   ( :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :occupation, 
   :hobbies,   :about_me)
 end
```

This is my stories index page where I try to list the story with the user's name who submits it

```
 <ul>
 <p>
 <% @stories.each do |story| %>
 <li><h1><%= link_to story.title, story %></h1>
 (<%= link_to story.category.category_name, 
 categories_path(@categories)  %>)
 Submitted by <%= link_to story.user.username ,
 profile_path(@profile) %>   &nbsp on 
 <%= story.created_at.strftime("%B-%d-%Y") %> </li>
 <% end %>
 </p>
 <br/>

 <div class="digg_pagination">
 <div class="page_info">
 <%= page_entries_info @stories %>
 </div>
 <%= will_paginate @stories, :container => false %>
 </div>
```

Here clicking on "story.user.username" should lead me to the profile show page of the user.However it throws me the following error

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Stories#index 
 Showing /home/mahesh/storyteller/app/views/stories/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Please help . Also let me know if I have to post some more info

Comment: show your story index method... probably `@profile` in the `link_to` method is `nil` try replacing `@profile` in `profile_path(@profile)` with `story.user` like in `profile_path(story.user)`

Comment: Yes..that worked ..thank you Minato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **@profile is passing as nil**, please check profile object , or you are trying to check story user profile then pass story.user inside

> profile_path(story.user)

.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to dynamic web development your idea to most with any experience is very simple. I decided to build your app's base functionality with minimal style keeping to the DRY practices of rails. It is [available for you to clone](https://github.com/Mr-Robot-Me/Story-app).

It is very hard for a  program developer to provide you with a clear answer, with the information you provided, plus from the syntax I've seen above your application could have under the hood issues as well.

It is also good practice to exercise programming terminology in descriptions of your applications functions and its attributes. ^R is a complex OOP language where R$ is a MVC architecture framework, if you can't describe it properly using PT it is hard for a developer to help you. It takes many failures to successfully become an  good and avid professional dev. (Persistence) is KEY VALUE = "diligence".

I have included a few Good online resources for RoR in the [Story-application](https://github.com/Mr-Robot-Me/Story-app) I developed for you to learn from. Please follow the read-me instruction.  Happy coding!

Comment: Ok...Thank you so much..i have cloned your application and will go through it.I guess I have a lot to learn.I hope I can seek more guidance from you...@Michael Devenport

Comment: Hi Mahesh, yes you are welcome to get in touch if you require any help. Go to http://www.youmix.me/contact and shoot me a message. Also find me at https://twitter.com/WEBrip Happy coding !